# Append in Julia

Tags: append, julia

I am new to Julia. A was curious how do I append values. I want b to grow every time the boolian value is True. And then to output its size.

```
function f(img_deformed, img)
    s = size(img)[1]
    for i in range(1,s,step=1)
        for j in range(1,s,step=1)
            b = img_deformed[i,j] == img[i,j]           
        end
    end
    return b
end
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `push!`

Comment: @DecowVR indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `b` to be a vector that tracks the number of times that the equality in your `for` loop is satisfied, you can use `push!`:

```
function f(img_deformed, img)
    s = size(img)[1]
    b = Vector{Bool}() # Can also use Bool[]
    for i in range(1,s,step=1)
        for j in range(1,s,step=1)
            if img_deformed[i,j] == img[i,j]
               push!(b, true)
            end           
        end
    end
    return length(b)
end
```

However, if all you really care about is the number of `true`s, it's easier (and almost certainly better) to just use `b` as a counter:

```
function f(img_deformed, img)
    s = size(img)[1]
    b = 0
    for i in range(1,s,step=1)
        for j in range(1,s,step=1)
            if img_deformed[i,j] == img[i,j]
               b += 1
            end          
        end
    end
    return b
end
```

Some minor style points: `s = size(img)[1]` is equivalent to `s = size(img, 1)`, and the `range(1, s, step=1)` is equivalent to `1:s`, so your code could be written slightly more simply as

```
function f(img_deformed, img)
    s = size(img, 1)
    b = 0
    r = 1:s
    for i in r
        for j in r
            if img_deformed[i,j] == img[i,j]
               b += 1
            end          
        end
    end
    return b
end
```

However, that doesn't address a potential mistake in the original code: unless you know that `img` will always be a square matrix, using the same range (`1:s`) for both `for` loops is not guaranteed to be correct. To avoid this problem, you can use [axes](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.axes-Tuple%7BAbstractArray,%20Any%7D):

```
function f(img_deformed, img)
    b = 0
    for j in axes(img, 2)
        for i in axes(img, 1)
            if img_deformed[i,j] == img[i,j]
               b += 1
            end          
        end
    end
    return b
end
```

Notice here that I've chosen to loop over the columns first; this is a good practice in Julia, since arrays are stored in column-major order (see the explanation [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-column-major) from the manual).

Note also that using `img` to control the values that we loop over implicitly assumes that `size(img) == size(img_deformed)`. Without knowing more about what this function is intended for, it's hard to suggest how to deal with that, but if you can assume that the two matrices *should* be the same size, you can add a check at the top of `f()`, e.g.

```
function f(img_deformed, img)
   @assert size(img) == size(img_deformed)
   # rest of code is the same
end
```

Comment: Lots of good advice in this answer, but an even better solution for indexing is to write `for i in eachindex(img, img_deformed)`. That will both choose the optimal indexing order (columnwise), and also error if the two arrays have incompatible sizes. It also works for arbitrary dimensions, not just 2D.

Comment: @DNF is totally right. I completely forgot about this particular `eachindex` method, but it's almost definitely what you should go with.

Comment: Oh, one more thing. It is possibly faster, and also more concise to do: `b += (img_deformed[i] == img[i])` instead of writing an `if` branch.

Comment: It's doubtful that would make much difference; Julia's compiler is usually smart enough to figure out that kind of thing on its own.

Indeed, some quick benchmarks using `BenchmarkTools` on 1000x1000 matrices shows no appreciable difference; defining `faxes` to use `axes`, `flinear` to use the linear indexing, and `flinear_noif` to use linear indexing with no `if` statement, the timings are all identical within measurement error (all about 950 microseconds on my machine).

Comment: I can't fit the full results in a comment, and I'm not sure it would be appropriate for a top-level answer, but I can provide the details if you like, although I didn't do anything fancy; should be easy enough to replicate :)